# How to resize bitmap bitmap loaded with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

Right now I have this:

```
       new BaseImageDecoder(false) {
            @Override
            protected BitmapFactory.Options prepareDecodingOptions(
                    ImageSize imageSize, ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) {
                // pass in a different imageSize, it might just work.
                ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(120, 80);
                return super.prepareDecodingOptions(targetSize, decodingInfo);
            }
        };
        DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .postProcessor(BitmapProcessor BaseImageDecoder)
                .build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, watermark, displayOptions, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) watermark.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) watermark.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//                saveBitmap(myBitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                myBitmap = loadedImage;
//                saveBitmap(myBitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) watermark.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//                saveBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        });
```

But it gives an "expression expected" on the line `.postProocessor( BaseImageDecoder)` so I think I am messing up some part of the implementation of this? How can I pass this to the options so that it is resized?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize any bitmap like this:

```
    int oldWidth = origImage.getWidth();
    int oldHeight = origImage.getHeight();

    int newWidth =  // 
    int newHeight = // some values you determine

    // calculate the scale
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
    float scaleHeight = ((float)newHeight) / oldHeight;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);


    // recreate the new scaled Bitmap
    Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(origImage, 0, 0,  oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
```

Comment: this is useful, but can you give me some tips on how to integrate this with an imageLoader from Universal Image Loader?

Answer (score 0):

Take that bit of code I gave you above.  Then insert it here:

```
@Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,   Bitmap loadedImage) {
            myBitmap = loadedImage;

            // insert code here to adjust image size
        }
```